# Add policy to header for react application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2

Hi we have a react application and we received a mail saying our application is missing few policies in the header.
The list they provided are as follows :

```
1.Strict transport security
2.Content security policy
3.X frame options
4.Referrer policy 
5.Permission policy
6.X content type options.
```

I’m unable to find solutions on how do I add these policies . I saw few links but they have given information what they are but not telling how to add them.

My application is hosted in aws using load balancer, we are not using nginx and back end is Java.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you check here in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) ... you can search for each header and add it to your fetch or w/e you use

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set these policies in client-side code since they are server response headers.   Is your back end hosted on EC2?

Comment: @jme11 yes backend is also in ec2